# Cleaning up an iOS App?

Tags: ios, refactoring

While I know there is no magical tool that will clean up the code for me, is there any tool that will highlight some of the unused classes/plists/localized strings/xibs and so on? I just took over an app that was built by a third party and it's a mess, I know a majority I'll have to fix manually, but I wasn't sure if there was anything that could get rid of the easy stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about it getting rid of stuff for you, but there's certainly a way to get some feedback on dodgy code. Select Product -> Analyze and that will run a build and analyze on your code. You'll get loads of feedback on possible memory leaks, variables that aren't used, along with all the usual warnings, etc.

Running Analyze frequently as you develop - just like doing a build except keyboard shortcut Shift+Cmd+B - is a great way to proactively trap dodgy code.

Comment: great idea! How do you do that?

Comment: Search for "analyze" in the build settings editor and turn that on.